Slug changes make header appear twice
I changed my slugs in the quick editor for SEO purposes. Now the header shows up twice.
I've tried creating a new header and select that over the existing one, but it still shows up twice. One is unedited, the other is the previously created header for the site. Now when I try to take my edits away, it still stays doubled up
[double header (mistake)] (https://i.sstatic.net/4awp6i0L.jpg)
[single header (intended)] (https://i.sstatic.net/1XZfBt3L.jpg)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
